# Reciprocal Pronouns (one another, each other) and Head Noun

Tags: syntax, nouns, pronouns

I have a question about Reciprocal Pronouns (a part of the category anaphors). I can't seem to find the entire answer that I am looking for anywhere, so I'll ask here. I have tried to make my question as broad as possible so that anyone else looking for the same information about Reciprocal Pronouns will find it.

My task is to analyze the Noun Phrases in a text. I need to find the head noun, and consequently categorize all of the other words in the NP.

I have run into this sentence:

> Then they started to chase *each other*.

I am having difficulty figuring out which of the words in this reciprocal pronoun is the head, and what the other word would be classified as.

My instincts tell me to treat it as one word, since it acts like a single word. If I were to do this, then it would be a NP with a single noun, and no modifiers.

I have spent hours trying to find an answer to this, so your advice and/or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't act like a single word. Note the paraphrase "Then they started to each chase the other (one)."

Comment: Your instinct serves you well. In your specific example they are written with a space as if they were two words, but the parts are inseparable and they are best regarded as a single pronoun. The antecedent is "they". There are other forms where the two components remain separate, with "each" and "one" determinatives and "other" a common noun, but that's not what you asked about

Comment: Thank you @GregLee , it's true that they can be separated. I didn't think of this since they are so commonly seen together.

Comment: Your answer @BillJ is precisely what I was looking for, and should I run into these two components separated (as you mentioned), I will know what to do.

Comment: Yes, in _Then they each started to chase the other_, "each" is an adjunct following the subject "they" and "other" is a common noun as head of the object NP.

Comment: Right. And they are related by the rule of Quantifier-Float. _Each man chased the other man_ becomes _Each man chased the other_ becomes _The men each chased the other_ becomes _The men chased each other_, which dispenses with the article.

Comment: point of info: in Arabic this is indeed one word, and it works in principle for any transitive verb.  from Daraba (he struck), taDarabuu - they (strove to) strike each other.  from lakama (he punched), talakamuu - they boxed (each other).